# Does not work base64.getEncoder android

Tags: java, android, base64

I can not connect the module java.util.Base64 to the android project.
I need to compare passwords, I take the hash code from the server to postgresql and compare it with the user entered. I use this code https://gist.github.com/lukaszb/1af1bd4233326e37a8a0.
But Base64 is not imported into the android project

Comment: Please learn to make a [MCVE] of your problem. Without it, the community will not understand what's troubling you and will have a really hard time answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, there is [android.util.Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html), bud does have a little different usage. However [java.util.Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64.html) is available in Android O Developer Preview. Alternatively, you can copy the source code of [java.util.Base64](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Base64.java) class into your project, but you'd have to release the project under the GPL license.

Comment: Copying the source code into the project wouldn't be a good idea unless the OP were also releasing their project under the GPL...